# OCR + QR Code Scanning at once

Tags: android, ocr, qr-code, barcode-scanner, android-vision

Using Android-Vision API can we do both thing i.e. QR Code Scanning and Barcode scanning at once?

Let me know if there is some provision already or some other way.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about QR Code + Barcode or OCR + Barcode?

The former one, when building BarcodeDetector, you can specify which Barcode types you'd like to detect and recognize, for example you can do Barcode.UPC_A | Barcode.QR_CODE.

The later one, you can mimic what we did in the demo app multiTracker
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision/blob/master/visionSamples/multi-tracker/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/samples/vision/face/multitracker/MultiTrackerActivity.java